# to get the weekdays between 2 dates

Tags: c#, .net

In my program there are two datetimepickers. I need to get the days in between the chosen dates and store them into a list or array. All these are to be done in the second datetimepicker value changed event

```
private void dateTimePickertodate_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dateTimePickertodate.Value <=dateTimePickerfromdate.Value)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Choose Correct date");
        textBoxnumofdays.Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        cleave = new LeaveApplication(constr);
        TimeSpan span = dateTimePickertodate.Value - dateTimePickerfromdate.Value;

        if (Mode == 1)
        {                       
            textBoxnumofdays.Text = Convert.ToString(span.Days + 2);
        }
        else
        {
            textBoxnumofdays.Text = Convert.ToString(span.Days + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What type of data you want to store in list or array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try something on these lines

```
DateTime dtFrom = new DateTime(2011, 02, 5);
DateTime dtTo = new DateTime(2011, 02, 9);
List<DayOfWeek> days = new List<DayOfWeek>();
while (dtTo != dtFrom)
{
   dtFrom = dtFrom.AddDays(1);
   days.Add(dtFrom.DayOfWeek);
}
```

days would have your week days list (if this is what you intent to have)

Answer (score 2):

You could try this to get all specified weekdays between two dates

```
    public List<DateTime> GetSelectedDaysInPeriod(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, List<DayOfWeek> daysToCheck)
    {
        var selectedDates = new List<DateTime>();

        if (startDate >= endDate)
            return selectedDates; //No days to return

        if (daysToCheck == null || daysToCheck.Count == 0)
            return selectedDates; //No days to select

        try
        {
            //Get the total number of days between the two dates
            var totalDays = (int)endDate.Subtract(startDate).TotalDays;

            //So.. we're creating a list of all dates between the two dates:
            var allDatesQry = from d in Enumerable.Range(1, totalDays)
                              select new DateTime(
                                            startDate.AddDays(d).Year,
                                            startDate.AddDays(d).Month,
                                            startDate.AddDays(d).Day);

            //And extracting those weekdays we explicitly wanted to return
            var selectedDatesQry = from d in allDatesQry
                                   where daysToCheck.Contains(d.DayOfWeek)
                                   select d;

            //Copying the IEnumerable to a List
            selectedDates = selectedDatesQry.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log error
            //...

            //And re-throw
            throw;
        }

        return selectedDates;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been answered here:
http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/48324-their-method-timespan-time-function

Also, you want to use the TotalDays property of TimeSpan and not just the day.

Comment: Please post the relevant bits, in case that site goes down.  SO should be independent of other sites.

Answer (score 0):

use [TimeSpan.TotalDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays.aspx)

the difference of 2 DateTimes is TimeSpan, which has property TotalDays, the count of days between 2 datetimes

Comment: OP asked for weekdays, not total days.